# Why is `--generator=deployment/apps.v1beta1` deprecated in `kubectl run`?

Tags: kubernetes

I saw generators except `run-pod/v1` are deprecated in [kubectl run](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#generators). Previously, it was convenient to create deployments without creating a YAML file for testing purposes, wondering why it is deprecated?

Comment: You can look in the code to see the change was made in this commit: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/2c4917db86d8df7a21ba2cc86d0a0635396cb29b. It references this PR: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/68132. You can read the original comment and ensuing discussion in the PR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.12.md#deprecations-and-removals):

> All kubectl run generators have been deprecated except for run-pod/v1. This is part of a move to make kubectl run simpler, enabling it create only pods; if additional resources are needed, you should use kubectl create instead. ([#68132](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/68132), @soltysh)